# Select appropriate enum class based on class member

Tags: java, enums, extends

I have an absract class that describes a general functionality of children classes.
When I initialize a child class I want to set a specific enum class as a member on the parent abstract class.
How can I do that?

Example:
AbstractFunctionality.java

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionality {
    protected String Name;
    protected String Surname;
    // specific enum class

    public AbstractFunctionality(String Name, String Surname){
         this.Name = Name;
         this.Surname = Surname;
    }
}
```

Child1.java

```
public class Child1 extends AbstractFunctionality {
    public Child1(){
        super("Jane","Austen");
    }
}
```

How can I specify that I want the `public enum Writers` in my `Child1` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler approach is just add the `enum` type as the type of the field parameter of the abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionality {
    protected String Name;
    protected String Surname;
    Writers writers;

    public AbstractFunctionality(String Name, String Surname, Writers writers){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Surname = Surname;
        this.writers = writers;
    }
}
```

the subclass:

```
public class Child1 extends AbstractFunctionality {
    public Child1(){
        super("Jane","Austen", Writers.SOME_FIELD);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make your enum `Writers` implement a more general `interface` let us say `IWriters`

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionality {
    protected String Name;
    protected String Surname;
    protected IWriters writers;

    public AbstractFunctionality(String Name, String Surname, IWriters writers){
         this.Name = Name;
         this.Surname = Surname;
         this.writers = writers;
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface IWriters {
     ... 
}
```

the enum:

```
public enum Writers implements IWriters{
    ...
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can have different enums types implementing the same interface, and therefore they can also be used on the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set generic in abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionality<T extends Enum<T>> {
    protected String Name;
    protected String Surname;
    T specificEnum

    public AbstractFunctionality(String Name, String Surname,T specificEnum){
         this.Name = Name;
         this.Surname = Surname;
         this.specificEnum=specificEnum;
    }
```

In the sub class

```
public class Child1 extends AbstractFunctionality<Writers> {
    public Child1(){
        super("Jane","Austen",Writers.POEM);
    }
}
}
```